# awk で斜めだけを取得するには？

Tags: awk

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

というデータ(`aa.txt`とします)があった時、
awkだけを使うという制約のもと、
斜めに1,5,9(または3,5,7)を取得するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？
私は

```
awk 'NR==i{print $i}' aa.txt
```

をループすればできると思ったのですが、うまくできませんでした

Answer (score 8):

```
 awk '{print $NR}' aa.txt
 awk '{print $(NF-NR+1)}' aa.txt
```

---

`NR`は処理している行の先頭からの番号(上から何行目か)が代入されている組み込みの変数です。

`NF`は処理している行のフィールド数(列の数)が代入されている組み込みの変数です。

`$`はフィールドを参照する演算子で、よく`$1`(=1列目)とか`$2`(=2列目)というふうに使われますが、`$(式)`という形で数字だけでなく式を与えることもできます。(※ひとつ目のコードは`()`を省略しています)

Comment: すごすぎてびっくり！！そもそも$NRってどういう意味ですか？

Comment: 回答に説明を追記いたしました。

Answer (score -1):

`$NR` ...terrible

```
awk '{(i=NR%NF)? 0:i=NF; print $i;}' aa.txt
awk '{(i=NR%NF)? i=NF-i+1:i=1; print $i;}' aa.txt
```